# Is it possible to get all stations of a city through HERE transit-api?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to locate all stations of a city through here's [transit-api](https://transit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json?)
but it seems there exists a constraint in the maximum number of results (50).
Are you aware of any other way?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is the accurate API to locate the near by transit stations, however it can only return 50 at a time. The alternative way to change centre and radius of the city to calculate all the transit stations.

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/public_transit/station-search-proximity
>
> https://transit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json?center=52.520501,13.403565&radius=1000&max=50&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxxx